# How to show columns under certain condition in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I am (new to) working in MySQL but so far I was getting along OK. Now I'm stuck on the following:

I want to show a column in the query result but only if a certain condition is met. If the condition is not met then I would like the column not to show up in the query result (rather than show an empty column with only NULL values).

I tried to use a CASE WHEN statement but in that case it always shows the column in the query result, even if it is empty.

The problem is that I need to do this for 12 columns. The main reason is to avoid the query result to be cluttered with useless empty columns. The result of the query is to be processed by other people in excel.

Thanks in advance for your kind replies.

Comment: I would suggest that a column with no data will provide its own information to your excel users. It will also remind them that those columns were actually queried and the lack of values is a positive reinforcement of the knowledge that that data is missing

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea and untimately requires *dynamic SQL*, not something you really want to dive into being new to MySql (and RDBMS in general?)

Comment: Use information_schema database; it is the data dictionary database for MySQL.

Comment: The query output structure is always static and deterministic. If you need the output structure to depend on some external condition then you must create two separate queries and execute according query matched the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Although not ideal, you could use a prepared statement to only select columns where some rows are `not null`.

Suppose you have this table `test` where `c` is `null` for all the rows:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | null |
| 2 | null | null |
| null | 3 | null |

You can do this:

```
SET @query = 'SELECT ';

SET @query = CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(a) FROM test) > 0 then CONCAT(@query, 'a,') ELSE @query END;
SET @query = CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(b) FROM test) > 0 then CONCAT(@query, 'b,') ELSE @query END;
SET @query = CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(c) FROM test) > 0 then CONCAT(@query, 'c,') ELSE @query END;

SET @query = CONCAT(TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM @query), ' FROM test');
```

Then:

```
PREPARE statement FROM @query; 
EXECUTE statement;
```

Output:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | null |
| null | 3 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e17c4d143c985dd2992ac026836ba5a7)